# Change all the values in a column based on column index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe.

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

I have a list of column indexes for a dataframe.

`list = [0,2]`

For each column index in that list, I want to change the values via `.apply`. Normally, I would have the column names in the list and do something like this:

```
for column in list:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(x)
```

However, this dataframe contains duplicate column names, so I can't use column names. What is the best way to apply changes to a column's values, only knowing the column index?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post sample data along with expected output

Comment: `df['x'] = df.apply(lambda row: x, axis=1)`

Comment: I can't see duplicate column names here. Please post a proper sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Use -

```
list_ = [0,2]
for i in list_:
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

**Output**

```
    0   1   2
0   2   2   4
1   5   5   7
2   8   8   10
```